# How to use Jquery to check checkbox states and do something based on conditions?

Tags: jquery, checkbox, conditional-statements

Here is my setup.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="item1" value="100" class="100" />
<input type="checkbox" name="item2" value="200" class="200" />
<input type="checkbox" name="item3" value="300" class="300" />

<p>$0.00</p>
```

The criteria I need is:
change P tag to the amount selected in the checkbox
if more than 1 checkbox is checked, add the amount together and display in P tag
if 1 or more checkbox is unchecked, subtract the amount and display in P tag
if none is selected or all of them are unchecked, display ZERO in the P tag.

I only have this so far but obviously it only displays the price of that selected box and doesn't add nor does it remove when I uncheck the box.

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").click(function() {
var amount = $(this).attr("class");
$("p").html("$"+amount);
});
```

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

simple try...

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").change(function() {
    var amount = 0;
    $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function(){
        amount += parseFloat(this.value,10);
    });
    $("p").html("$"+amount);
});
```

## [Crazy demo](http://jsfiddle.net/reigel/r3ZTX/)

Comment: Thanks! that works however, I am trying to extract the amount from the class not from value...can that be done?

Comment: change `this.value` to `this.class`.. that is, if you have just the price in the class then that would work as expected... :D

Comment: Ok, so close...I've changed it but now it displays NaN

Comment: Ok, I figured it out..I had to change it to parseFloat($(this).attr("class"),10);